# Avoid specifying an outer class when using its nested class outside

Tags: apex, class, nested

How can I avoid specifying an outer class when using its nested class outside the outer?

For example, I have the following:

```
public with sharing class ClassA {
    public class NestedInA {

    }
}

public with sharing class ClassB {
    public void methodWhicUsesNestedInA() {
        ClassA.NestedInA nestedInA = new ClassA.NestedInA();
    }
}
```

I do not want to always write `ClassA.NestedInA` when I am using the `NestedInA` class inside `ClassB`. I would like to be able to write `NestedInA` instead. Is it possible? If so, then how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately. Apex does not have an "import" function that you might expect from another C-family language, Python, etc. `ClassA.NextedInA` is going to be called exactly that everywhere *except* inside the scope of `ClassA`.

Your only option is to promote the inner class to its own outer class.